# How do I POST from an iframe to another page outside the iframe?

Tags: iframe, post, redirect

Within an iframe I have a user validate credit card payment information with a 3rd party website and upon validation the page will redirect to a predefined URL within our application. However, it POSTs to this URL within the iframe itself. Is there a clean way to redirect to the page I need? or do I have to use some intermediate page that would then do the redirect 'out' of the iframe?

Comment: Or do this :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the following javascript in your returned to page.

```
window.parent.location = url;
```

Comment: Actually this is a GET, not a POST.  As this might solve the original person's problem, it may be useful for him ... I would just add a disclaimer that this is a GET, as opposed to a POST.