# how to pass php variable through iframe to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, getelementbyid

I am trying to pass a php variable value, through an iframe over to a javascript variable.
All files are on my own server and domain.

This is my html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php 
        $userOutput = "bob"; 
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="test123"><?=$userOutput?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

And in my original page i try to access the information like this:

```
<iframe id="iframeId" src="http://path/to/file.html"></iframe>
<script>
   window.onload = function() {
      var iframeDoc = document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.document;
      var test = iframeDoc.getElementById('test123').value;
      console.log(test);
   };
</script>
```

Now, i do manage to reach my content, and i have tried before to just get the value of some input field i put in my "file.html" with success, but i can't seem to reach the php variable value ("test" shows up as undefined)

Comment: After running your code it seems to work fine? In the file where your php variable is, did you save the file as a .php?

Comment: It is saved as an html file and the php is sort of embedded in it.

Comment: so where `$userOutput` is, i saved it as say file.php and then the other file where the JS is I saved it as file2.html and all works fine? Are you able to run `phpinfo();` in your .php file. Just to be sure php is setup as it should be.

Comment: just to make it clearer.
I have one html file with php embedded into it (file.html)
I have another html file with javascript embedded into it (file2.html) that accesses "file.html" through an iframe element.

Comment: Well, `file.html` should be `file.php` and file2.html can stay as it is. Anything with php in should have the `.php` extension rather than the `.html` unless you're running things like AngularJS

Comment: That worked! i see the value now!
would you like to provide this as an answer so i can mark it as the correct solution for my question?

Comment: Made it a little more in depth so have a read on the answer too. Glad you've resolved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So anything that holds php needs to go into a .php file rather than a .html

as an example:

`variableStored.php`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php
    $userOutput = "Frrrrrrr";
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="test123">
        <?php echo $userOutput; ?>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Take Note**: when echo'ing out, its always best to `<?php echo 'something';?>`

rather than `<?='something'?>`

Then within lets say `iframe.html`:

```
<iframe id="iframeId" src="http://siteurl/variableStored.php"></iframe>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var iframeDoc = document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.document;
        var test = iframeDoc.getElementById('test123').value;
        console.log(test);
    };
</script>
```

This will then fetch everything from `variableStored.php` as you want it to.

Comment: Thanks! changed it to <?php echo xxxx ?> as well.

Comment: No problem at all!

Answer (score 0):

You could `echo` your variable in a Javascript variable like

```
<script>var test = "<?= $variable ?>";</script>
```

And pass the variable as GET parameter to your iframe.

```
<script>
        var url = "myIframe.html?var1=" + test; 
        $('#myIframe').attr('src', url"); 
</script>
```

You can then retreive the info using

```
<script>
function getParamValue(paramName)
{
    var url = window.location.search.substring(1); //get rid of "?" in querystring
    var qArray = url.split('&'); //get key-value pairs
    for (var i = 0; i < qArray.length; i++) 
    {
        var pArr = qArray[i].split('='); //split key and value
        if (pArr[0] == paramName) 
            return pArr[1]; //return value
    }
}
</script>
```

I want to give credit to @Ozgur bar for his answer here. [How to pass parameters through iframe from parent html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295870/how-to-pass-parameters-through-iframe-from-parent-html)

Comment: @Option I didn't actually. Should i ?

Comment: I would, it works okay for me so I can only assume it's to do with the Ops PHP on the Ops local machine.

Comment: Probably, worst case scenario, i simply suggested a new approach. Thanks for the feedback thought.