# How can I open folder with main domain which is located in iframe from another domain?

Tags: javascript

I have several websites like `test1.com`, `test2.com`, `test3.com`

In all of them located same iframe like: 
`<iframe src="http://iftametest.com"></iframe>`

In this `iframe` I wrote a link like `<a href="/demo">Demo</a>`

I want to open `/demo` page, which is located in `iframe`, from `main domain`. Example: If I click to `/demo` in `iframe` from main domain `test1.com`, should be opened `test1.com/demo`. The same should be for `test2.com` and `test3.com`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question isn't clear to me, I think you need to show more of your code, and tell us what is going wrong, and what you would like to see.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters through iframe from parent html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295870/how-to-pass-parameters-through-iframe-from-parent-html)