# How to retrieve atributes from iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, iframe

I have an app which I am inserting another app using iframe as follows

Parent App

```
<HTML>
....
<body>
<iframe firstname="Trump" src="https://on.co/onboarding/" height="600" allowfullscreen="" > 
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Children App

```
<HTML>
....
<body>
  <h1> Covid is deadly if you doubt  ask the indians </h1>

  <script>
   const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
   const myParam = urlParams.get('firstname');
   console.log(myParam) //undefined
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to get the first name from the iframe URL parameters

**I get undefined**

What is wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28296334/13983399

Comment: The url has no search params

Comment: @Musa what do you mean?

Comment: `https://on.co/onboarding/` does not have a firstname parameter, it has no parameters at all

Comment: okay i changes to how to get attributes from iframe

Comment: Don't use attributes. Use a query string.

Comment: Is `parent app` also hosted on `https://on.co` ?  If so, you can do it.  If not, it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need:

```
<iframe src="https://on.co/onboarding/?firstname=SomeName" height="600" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like you're trying to get an element `attribute`, not a `url parameter`. You can get attributes using the `getAttribute` method on an element, e.g.

```js
const myIframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
const firstname = myIframe?.getAttribute('firstname');
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Note however that the `firstname` attribute is useless on an `iframe`, so you should reconsider how you got it there in the first place.

Comment: @TheDeadMan I see your question, but it's not consistent with the snippet you've provided. The URL you showed simply does not have a `firstname` URL parameter, however the iframe *does* have a `firstname` attribute. So your problem is less 'how to get the parameter', and instead 'how did my iframe get like this in the first place'

Comment: The iframe is in the parent frame, so you can't search `document` for it (and you can't access it across origins)

Comment: Thanks @Quentin, I glanced over that. However IMO the problem is still that the iframe is invalid for what OP expects

Comment: I change the question maybe now is undestandable