# How to know when an iframe comes into view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

If I have a site that holds an iframe:

```
<html>

    <body>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <iframe src="http:/somelink.com/iframe.html"></iframe>
    </body>

</html>
```

Is it then possible for the iframe to know if it can be "seen"?
This for example by knowing the top position of the iframe related to the top of the screen.

This is my test iframe:
(all values are 0, no matter scroll pos of parent)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {
                console.log("ok");  

                check();

            });


            function check() {

                // position of parent
                var parentScrollTop = $(window.parent.document).scrollTop();
                console.log("parentScrollTop: "+parentScrollTop);

                // self position
                var bodyPosition = $("body").position().top;
                console.log("body position: "+bodyPosition);

                setInterval(check, 1000);
            }

        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

I made an image to be more clear.
[image]

I have to know from within the iframe if it's visible or not!
So not from within the page that holds the iframe.

Comment: can you jsfiddle this?

Comment: yeah give me a few minutes

Comment: This is horrible for jsfiddle!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if element is visible after scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

Comment: It is not an duplicate. This is way more tricky...

Comment: @clankill3r Agreed this is not duplicate after your edit

Comment: You might want to check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/q/536538/2317532. The solution involves using `window.parent`

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but some new API from Chrome have been released that could answer your question on the latest versions of Chrome (22+)

The `InteractionObserver` you can find it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

There is a polyfill that is being developped (same repo) but it will not work from within the iframe afaik only if the script is on the parent webpage.

For other browsers their is some dark ways to do it based on timing attack, this article explains it pretty well: https://www.contextis.com/media/downloads/Pixel_Perfect_Timing_Attacks_with_HTML5_Whitepaper.pdf

*Edit: Next **Firefox** version to come has the `InteractionObserver` feature activated by default now, Same for **Edge** !*

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: I fixed @trysis

Comment: Thanks. It may be worth noting there's a polyfill for browsers that don't have IntersectionObserver.

Comment: There is but it is based on position of the elements and it will not work if you're in an iframe.

Comment: Not sure if this applies everywhere, but the <html> element of my <iframe> had some intersection or not depending on whether the <iframe> had `display: none`. The <body> element and, obviously, everything inside <body>, always had some intersection.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible

Add an id to the iframe then you can use this:

```
if ($('#iframeID').visible(true)) {
  // The iframe is visible
} else {
  // The iframe is NOT visible
}
```

Comment: I thought `.visible` checks whether the CSS `visibility` property is set to `visible`, not whether it is in view

Comment: apologies, forgot the link to github - added now

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar issue with [detecting infinite scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9439725/2317532) - How do we know the 'Load more' button is visible?

As an extension to the above link, you can also [write a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/488073/2317532) which will detect if any element is visible (on the y-axis) (copied over for reference):

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var $window = $(window);

    var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

    var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

Comment: It's not similar. The problem is I have to know from within the iframe. Not the page that holds the iframe.

Comment: @clankill3r I see, that's a different ballpark altogether! It's good you edited your question to clarify this.

Comment: Yeah everyone seems to understand it wrong :) I'm not that good in explaining things it seems :)

Comment: O yeah, i get 'TypeError: $elem.offset(...) is undefined'

Comment: Also, why do you use $window.height()? This means the longer the page the higher the value of docViewBottom and therefor it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. It requires that the page holding the iframe has jQuery.

```
function isScrolledIntoParentView(elem) {


                var $elem = window.parent.$(elem);

                var docViewTop = $(window.parent).scrollTop();
                var docViewBottom = docViewTop + window.parent.innerHeight;

                var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
                var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

                console.log("isScrolledIntoParentView");
                console.log($elem);
                console.log("docViewTop "+docViewTop);
                console.log("docViewBottom "+docViewBottom);
                console.log("elemTop "+elemTop);
                console.log("elemBottom "+elemBottom);

                return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
            }
```