# How to pass data from MVC Controller to ASPX Page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have two projects (one ASP.NET MVC and one ASP.NET Webform). I am showing the aspx page of webform project in one panel of the cshtml page of MVC project.

I wanted to pass a value from the action method of controller to the aspx page and I need to  use it in the webform project. Could some one help how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is the WebForms page being referenced by the MVC view?  Can you show how you're accomplishing this?

Comment: are both MVC and Webforms, arei n the same domain or in different domains?

Comment: Hi David, With the help of <iframe id="ID" src='@Url.Action("ActionMethod","Controller")'> </iframe> we can do this.

Comment: Hi Ramiramilu, Nope... they are in different domains.

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/536538/304683) helps/viable. Hth..