# How to pass value from parent to its iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

Hi i want to pass the value by calling the parent link page value to its iframe link page 
sample code is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
        <script>
            function sendvalue(v){
                alert(v);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="f">
            <input type="button" value="123" onclick="sendvalue(this.value)">
        </form>
        <iframe id="frame1" src="a.html" width="500px;"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

a.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
        <script>

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3> Frame</h3>
        <form id="myform">
            Req value <input type="text" name="a" id="a">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

when i call sendvalue function then the value should pass to iframe link page in form for input field.
how this can be achieved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass value to iframe from a window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536538/pass-value-to-iframe-from-a-window)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935127/how-to-access-parent-iframe-from-javascript

Comment: https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-pass-data-between-iframe-and-parent-window/

Answer (score 3):

You can use `postMessage` in order to communicate between 2 iframe.

On the parent frame you need to grab the iframe's window with `iframeEl.contentWindow.postMessage(value as a string, can be json.stringified value)`

On the child frame you need to add event of type `message`, something like that:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(dataPassed) {
   //Your logic here.
})
```

For more info [read that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
<script>
function sendvalue(v){
document.getElementById('va').value = v;
window.frames['framename'].document.getElementById("a").value = v


}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="f">
 <input type="button" value="123" onclick="sendvalue(this.value)">
 <input type="text" name="va" id="va">
</form>
<iframe  name="framename" src="a.html" width="500px;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

a.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3> Frame</h3>
<form id="myform">
Req value <input type="text" name="a" id="a">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Best way it 
to add to you Iframe

```
<iframe id="frame1" src="a.html?data=SomeData" width="500px;"></iframe>
```

and inside the iframe you can get the information by making varible

```
var MYDATA = location.href.split('=')[1].split('&');
```

(you will see that **MYDATA=SomeData**)