# Passing angular-2 (typescript) global variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want something like that [Example 1](http://%20http://www.coderzheaven.com/2017/01/10/how-to-call-android-function-from-javascript/) and [Example 2](https://www.tanelikorri.com/tutorial/android/communication-between-application-and-webview/). 
I create a ionic project and create a .html file. Then open that file in pages/home.ts file inside iframe.

**pages/home.ts**

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

my_url: any;

constructor(private sanitize: DomSanitizer) {
}

urlpaste(){
this.my_url = "assets/imgs/ankur.html";
return this.sanitize.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.my_url);
}

pass_to_ankur(){
//how to pass any text in ankur.html file with this function
}
```

**pages/home.html**

```
<ion-content>

<iframe height="100%"  width="100%" [src]="urlpaste()"></iframe>

</ion-content>


<ion-footer>
 <ion-toolbar (click)="pass_to_ankur()">
  <ion-title>Pass variable</ion-title>
 </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

And my ankur.html file path inside ionic project "assets/imgs/ankur.html". I want I press "pass variable" footer and value pass in ankur.html file. How it possible. I see many examples but maximum android native to html page connectivity. But i want in ionic project.

**ankur.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <h1>My First Heading</h1>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
 </body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  alert("call==");
 </script>
</html>
```

Please help because I try to many days but not given any solution. :( Please understand my problem and resolve my issue. Sorry for my weak english. ThankYou

Comment: Check below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536538/pass-value-to-iframe-from-a-window

Comment: @Shriniwas I want pass any data pass JS file to TS file.