# Add string to iframe parameters

Tags: javascript

I am loading the contents of an `iframe` based on the results of a SQL query which takes UI input. As such, the height of the iframe needs to be changed regularly in order for the page formatting to remain constant.

When the page loads initially, I use the following to determine the `iframe`'s height:

```
onload="this.height=this.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;"
```

This works when the page is loaded for the first time; but when the user dynamically changes the `iframe`'s content, the onload is not retriggered, and the `iframe` retains its original height.

This is how the `iframe` is presented in my index.php when the page is initially loaded:

```
<script>document.write('<iframe id="mainpage-iframe" onload="this.height=this.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;" src="page-body.php"></iframe>');</script>
```

When the user makes choices from a menu to update the `iframe` based on results from a SQL query, a function such as the following is triggered:

```
document.getElementById('mainpage-iframe').contentDocument.location.assign('page-body.php?selectvenue=' + venue + '&selectcity=' + city);
```

...which posts arguments to page-body.php.

So, my question is: is it possible to somehow 'append' to this result in order that the `document.write` function includes the `onload` action?

Comment: See this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536538/pass-value-to-iframe-from-a-window

Comment: Also use      `$(document).ready(function(` http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1748185&seqNum=2

Comment: Thanks @i_th but the onload occurs in index.html, not in the iframe document.

Comment: Add the load handler _inside_ page-body.php, make the iframe detect the height of its own content, and then have it access the parent window to set the height of the iframe element there …

Comment: @misorude Great idea. But how can I pass the value back to the already-loaded page and have it reset the height?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935127/how-to-access-parent-iframe-from-javascript explains how to access the iframe parent window.

Comment: While that does seem like a good idea, I feel that it would be complicating things unnecessarily... Isn't it possible to simply also trigger the `onload` function then the iframe URL is updated?

Comment: Hmm, the more I think about, the more I am coming around on your suggestion though... it really just comes down to passing the height of the iframe's contents back to the mainpage....

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery to update the height on resize

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        //Update height here
    }
}
```