# Setting the HTTP request type of an <iframe>

Tags: html, iframe

Is it possible to make an iframe use a POST rather than a GET request? I am not trying to post a form into the iframe but load the iframe depending on data generated on the server.

Unfortunately, I can't use Javascript in this case (because it is the company's policy that the checkout must be possible without JS).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `IFRAME SRC="/yourscript"` always uses a GET.

(You could `POST` to the `IFRAME`, or you can `GET` a page inside the `IFRAME` that `POST`s a form using JS; but you specifically said those aren't viable for you)