# How to send parameter to Iframe with a HTTP POST request

Tags: javascript, html, http, iframe

I have to send some parameter to an IFRAME with POST method.
I have read here [Setting the HTTP request type of an <iframe>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802894/setting-the-http-request-type-of-an-iframe) that it isn't possible. I'm thinking a solution in Javascript but I can't implement it so I can't test if it is a valid solution for this issue.
I want to ask if someone has the same problem and if it is possible to solve and in positive case how to?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
<form ... target="hidden_iframe">
...
</form>

<iframe name="hidden_iframe" ...></iframe>
```

Comment: just make the form invisible and the iframe too.. and then do a form submit via js

Answer (score 32):

How about using the target attribute of the form to point to iFrame?

```
 <form target="myIframe" action="http://localhost/post.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="someval" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<iFrame src="" name="myIframe"></iFrame>
```

Comment: What does post.php do? Why is this necessary?

Comment: @Kalina this is late obviously but it is the url that you want to send the post request to

Answer (score 24):

Just to give a concrete working example

```
<form id="loginForm" target="myFrame"  action="https://localhost/j_spring_security_check" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="j_username" value="login" />
 <input type="text" name="j_password" value="password" />
 <input type="submit">
</form>

<iframe name="myFrame" src="#">
   Your browser does not support inline frames.
</iframe>

// Hide the form and do the submit 
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var loginform= document.getElementById("loginForm");
 loginform.style.display = "none";
 loginform.submit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Using a hidden form and then submitting it does not makes sense. Why not just use an ajax request and populate the target div with the response received?

Comment: haven't you try it?

Comment: how can I add headers?

Answer (score 0):

Proposed solution works almost fine in my case, problem is that my form submitting returns an authorization cookie. Website that is rendering iframe is located on different domain that iframe website and this method returns me an error that I can't set the cookies. Is there a secure way to fix this?

[image]