# IE Issue: Submitting form to an iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe

I was trying to create an iframe element using javascript, like so:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.setAttribute('name', 'frame_x');
```

However, when I tried submitting a form using the newly-created iframe as target, IE opens up a new window, instead of using the iframe.

```
form.setAttribute('target', 'frame_x');
form.submit();
```

This works perfectly in Firefox. Also, the iframe gets created, but is not used.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You've hit a **[bug in Internet Explorer](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/10/bug-235-createelement-is-broken-in-ie.html)**.

You **CAN NOT** set the name attribute of *ANY* element in IE using the standard DOM Method ***`.setAttribute('name', value);`***

In IE (before version 8 running in IE8 standards mode) this method will not work to set the name attribute.

You need to use one of the following:

```
//A (any browser)
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.name = 'frame_x';

//B (only in IE)
var iframe = document.createElement('<iframe name="frame_x"/>');

//C (use a JS library that fixes the bug (e.g. jQuery))
var iframe = $('<iframe name="frame_x"></iframe>');

//D (using jQuery to set the attribute on an existing element)
$('iframe:first').attr('name','frame_x');
```

Comment: Solution A does not seem to work in IE 9 in compatibility mode. Solution B does work however.

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to SO.

One issue I saw in your code is that you're never actually displaying the iframe. In order for it to appear on the page, you have to insert it into your document.  In my example, I create a `<span>` tag to act as the slot where the iframe will get inserted.

See if this does what you're looking for.

```
<!-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181385/ie-issue-submitting-form-to-an-iframe-using-javascript -->

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitFormToIFrame(){
    var form=document.getElementById('myform');
    form.setAttribute('target', 'frame_x');
    form.submit();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hello Erwin!</h1>

<form id="myform" name="myform" action="result.html">
    <input type="button" value="Submit the Form" onClick="submitFormToIFrame();">
</form>


<span id="iframeSlot">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.setAttribute('name', 'frame_x');
    document.getElementById('iframeSlot').appendChild(iframe);
</script>
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I found that this solution is only working in Firefox.  So I did some experimenting.  It seems that if you define the iframe in the html (instead of generating it via JS/DOM) then it works.  Here is the version that works with IE and Firefox:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitFormToIFrame(){
    //IE
    if( document.myform ){
        document.myform.setAttribute('target','frame_x');
        document.myform.submit();
    //FF
    } else {
        var form=document.getElementById('myform');
        form.setAttribute('target', 'frame_x');
        form.submit();
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hello Erwin!</h1>

<form id="myform" name="myform" action="result.html" target="">
    <input type="button" value="Submit the Form" onClick="submitFormToIFrame();">
</form>

<span id="iframeSlot">
<iframe name="frame_x">
</iframe>
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. Actually, I didn't include in my post the part where the iframe gets appended to a div element, and the element to the document.body (using appendChild).

Given that the iframe has already been added to the body, the form is still not targetting the iframe. But this only occurs in IE.

Comment: @Erwin, you are absolutely right.  I've been experimenting with this and I updated my answer.  Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked! Nice one. However, I still have some unresolved questions.

What could have been the difference? Isn't it enough just to have a reference to the form object (using getElementById in this case)?

Also, when I tried creating the form using javascript, instead of having a form element inside the html, the same problem re-occurred. But this time, the if-else clause for IE/FF implementations no longer seems to work. Any idea?

But still, thanks for the answer!

Comment: see my answer for why it didn't work at first... you can't use setAttribute() to set the name in IE.

Comment: The `if` statement seems rather redundant here, the code that works for Firefox should work just as well for IE, so there's no point to the IE-specific code.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendForm(idform){
    var nfi = "RunF"+tagRandom();
    $("body").append("<iframe name=\""+nfi+"\" id=\""+nfi+"\" class=\"runAgents\" src=\"#\"></iframe>");
    $("#"+idform).attr("target",nfi);
    $("#"+idform).submit();
}
```

Comment: Its helpful to add some type of comment with your answer to explain how your code helps.

Answer (score 0):

To continue @scunliffe’s answer, if using Prototype.js:

```
var iframe = Element('iframe', {name: 'frame_x'});
```

which works because this helper function detects `HAS_EXTENDED_CREATE_ELEMENT_SYNTAX` for IE, working around the `.name = …` bug.