# IE9 opens new tab on form submit ( form has target attibute, pointed to dynamically created iframe )

Tags: javascript, post, internet-explorer-9

I have a javascript function which dynamically creates an iframe for a form, so the form is sent to iframe. The code works in Chrome, Opera and Firefox, but IE opens new tab when I submit the form.

how to fix this issue?

**HTML**:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="/post.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="foo" value="bar">
  <button type="submit" name="send">Send</button>
</form>
```

**Javascript** *(runs on page load)*:

```
var form = document.getElementById("form1");
if(!form.target) {
  var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
  frame.name = "frame" + Math.random();
  frame.id = frame.name;

  document.body.appendChild(frame);

  form.target = frame.id;
}
```

Comment: @Adriano I don't think so

Comment: @Adriano: It's a `POST`, not a `GET`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the code is executed on page load

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you post to an iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder right, missed that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's the point. As the accepted answer says this is a known bug of IE and there are workarounds there.

Comment: @Adriano: Ah! See, one had to read past the opening paragraph. :-)

Comment: @Adriano, thanks for the sugesstion, the workaround seems to work

Comment: More direct link to don't have to search through the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181385/ie-issue-submitting-form-to-an-iframe-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

form.target must be iframe name, not id.