# Is posible to submit multipart/form-data without refresh page in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, upload, submit, multipartform-data

I want to upload picture from "my_form" in jQuery, I tried submit() function it alway redirect to SavePicture.jsp. Is posible to sumbit this form without refresh any page?

This is my html code

```
<form action="SavePicture.jsp" method="post" id="my_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="file" type="file" id="file" size="35">
<input type="button" onClick="upload()" value="upload"></input>
</form>
```

And my script

```
function upload(){
   jQuery("form#my_form").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [post to an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe/168488#168488)

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [JQuery form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin, or to see the progress of uploads [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) (requires flash)