# Render VueJs page in IFrame with POST method

Tags: post, iframe, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to render an Vuejs App in an iFrame, in POST with some params.

So I need to call my Vuejs url `POST http://localhost:8080`, but I can't :

`Cannot POST /`

It is possible to avoid this problem ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you want but if you want to load Vuejs in an iframe, I'd probably pass some query parameters like this:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:8080?queryParameter=1&queryParameter=2&queryParameter3" />
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, 
unfortunately I need to pass my params with POST method, not GET. That's why I use a form, but I get a `Cannot POST /`

Comment: Is there a special config for webpack (4) to allow POST method ?

Comment: Maybe try this? First link on google https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803320/sending-data-through-post-method-to-an-iframe