# Submitting a form through a modal box without leaving the page/modal

Tags: php, javascript, mootools, persistence, modal-dialog

I am using the project 'ModalBox' from http://okonet.ru/projects/modalbox/index.html in order to generate my modal.

I am also using this overall script that persists e-mails submitted via form into a basic text file as a simple/quick solution. http://www.knowledgesutra.com/forums/topic/25586-php-simple-newsletter-script/

I have a dilemma though.
In order to keep the modal and display my 'mailing_thankyou.php' my form has to have 'onsubmit="return false"' but in order for my php script to work, I have to remove that return false, but then it changes to a new page in order to persist that information.

Does anyone have any ideas?

This is the main part in question:

*myModal.html*

```
<div id="signUp">
<form action="mailer/mailing.php" id="myForm" method="post" class="style16">
    <input type="text" name="email" size="30" value="your email here!">
    <input type="submit" value="Send link" name="submit" onclick="Modalbox.show('mailer/mailing_thankyou.php', {title: 'Form sending status', width: 500, params:Form.serialize('myForm') }); return false;">
    &nbsp;or&nbsp;<a href="#" title="Cancel &amp; close dialog" onclick="Modalbox.hide(); return false;">Cancel &amp; close</a>
    <!-- ><input type="submit" value="GO!" name="submit"> -->
    </form>
</div>
```

You may pull my files from my git repo: 
https://github.com/jwmann/Modal-Sign-up

Comment: Try an ajax post onsubmit to your mailing.php file, then on success you can call Modalbox.show. Can you use jQuery? It's very simple, e.g.:
$.post('mailer/mailing.php', function(data) {
  Modalbox.show(...);
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the 'return false' from the input submit's 'onsubmit' (duhhh *facepalm*) because it was trying to serialize it in the first palce with prototype.js

Then I changed the php script so it would grab with $_GET instead of $_POST

no added functionality or hacks needed. Thank you for all the help though.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not good at Mootools, so I will give you an example in jQuery - if you get the idea, I'm pretty sure you will find the right syntax for Mootools too.

The idea is to use AJAX call for form submission (and keep the `onsubmit="return false;"` so that browser window isn't reloaded):

```
var $form = $('#myForm');
$.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(response) {
    $('div#signUp').html(response);
});
```

What this does is:

1. Stores jQuery wrapped form element into `$form`
2. Uses form's `action` attribute value as a request target address
3. Serializes and transfers all form elements' values
4. Executes callback function, which takes returned HTML code and replaces contents of `<div id='signUp'>...</div>` with this HTML.

Note: make sure that the script at forms `action` only returns html for the contents of the sign up box (meaning no `<head>`, `<body>`, etc. - only what should be in the box afterwards)

**EDIT/AMENDMENT**

This is what I've just found out on [MooTools Docs page for Ajax/Request](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request.HTML):

The equivalent of my jQuery snippet in MooTools would be

```
new Request.HTML({                     // Creates an AJAX request
    'url': $('myForm').get('action'),  // Sets request address to the form's action
    'update': $('signUp')              // Indicates that results should be auto-loaded into element with id='signUp'
}).post($('myForm'));                  // Indicates that this form has to be serialized and transferred; also starts the request process
```

This requires that the form's action returns the result to display (a thank you message). One could achieve that by making redirect from the server-side after form data has been successfully processed, e.g. in PHP `header('Location: mailer/mailing_thankyou.php'); exit;`

After looking longer at your code I realized, that this is not entirely what you want (as I see you don't want the form replaced with the thank-you message - you want it to be shown in the modal). Hence the updated solution for your case:

```
new Request.HTML({                     // Creates an AJAX request
    'url': $('myForm').get('action'),  // Sets request address to the form's action
    'onSuccess': function() {          // Defines what to do when request is successful (similarly you should take care of error cases with onFailure declaration
        Modalbox.show('mailer/mailing_thankyou.php', {
            title: 'Form sending status', 
            width: 500
            // I have removed params from here, because they are handled in the .post() below
        });
    }
}).post($('myForm'));                  // Indicates that this form has to be serialized and transferred; also starts the request process
```

Pardon me if any of this doesn't work (as I said, I'm more of a jQuery guy - just trying to help here)

Comment: I'd rather not use 2 javascript libs, would you know how to do this with mootools?

Comment: Or how would I integrate this into what I already have? I added what you said (with jQuery included) and it just broke the modal (it didn't grab the myModal.html file)

Comment: I agree with you that mixing different frameworks isn't a good idea (although possible by taking precautions, like `jQuery.noConflict()`). Plese find the added solution in MooTools code

Comment: I'm not sure how to invoke this request. I tried it via function call but apparently 'Request' undefined. I've updated my git repo in order show these changes. (thanks for the update btw, truly appreciate it.)

Comment: `Request.HTML` should be a class provided to you by MooTools (at least docs say that it's in the core, so I don't see how it could be undefined - maybe you have some modified/stripped version?)

Comment: I see, I think 'Modal box' is using a stripped down version of mootools. When I include the mootools library, I think there are some conflicts. How should I approach this? should I attempt to use jQuery along with my ModalBox? Assuming I use this 'noconflict' function? I'm more of a jQuery guy myself.

Answer (score 0):

Have the form submit to a hidden iframe on the page. Give the iframe a name value and then set a target propery on the form. You can make the iframe 1x1 pixel and set the `visibility` to `hidden` (if you hide via `display: none` it might not work in all browsers.)

See this question for details: 
[How do you post to an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe)

Comment: Why use a hack when there is a solution?

Comment: This is shorter and has the added benefit of working cross-domain. It's what most cross-domain solutions do internally.