# How can I get Dreamweaver to use the "id" attribute instead of "name"?

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I am new to web development and I have been taking a class through Lynda.com on how to use Dreamweaver CS5. I try to spend most of my time hand coding and use the Dreamweaver tutorial as an intro to HTML. However, I have noticed that when I do use Dreamweaver to enter certain elements in, such as forms, it uses the "name" attribute and not the "id" attribute. From what I have learned, "name" has been abandoned in favor of "id". Is this the case for all tags, such as forms? If so, how can I set Dreamweaver to use "id" in this case, instead of "name"?

Please forgive me if this has already been answered. I searched for it, and did not come across it, but since I am new to Stackoverflow, it might just be that I didnt search correctly.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Perhaps I should add that I am trying to learn standards compliant HTML5 at this point in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, Dreamweaver is correct. For a server-side programming language to process the form data (as POST or GET data), each form element must have a name="" attribute set.

You can still manually type id="" in the HTML if you need it, but Dreamweaver autogenerating name attributes for form elements is very sensical if the form is to be used.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="message1" id="styleme" value="Hey there!" />
```

**CSS**

```
#styleme { font-size: 18px; }
```

**PHP**

```
<?php echo $_POST['message1']; ?>
```

Comment: Wow. That was explained perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**name** attributes are still required for form elements as [Chris G.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127809/how-can-i-get-dreamweaver-to-use-the-id-attribute-instead-of-name/7127827#7127827) noted up, [maps](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) and [frames](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp) ([iframes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) among them). Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe) for the example of **name** usage on iframe.

**id** is way to uniquely identify DOM element, mostly for styling or scripting purposes.