# How not to redirect when submitting a form inside of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, http

I'm trying to submit a form as a POST request with pre-loaded data to a site with no API. I have wrapped my form inside an iframe element, hoping to isolate it. However, the page still changes to the action page. How can I trap it in to prevent this?

Some answers to similar questions suggest setting the response's Content-Type to text/plain to force the browser to treat it as a document instead of a file. However, please note that I don't have access to the other end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to wrap the `form` in an `iframe`. Keep the form on the main page and create a hidden, separate `iframe` on the same page. Then you need to use the form's `target` attribute to let the `iframe` become the target for the result of the POST operation. This way when submitting the `form` you will stay on the page, and the results will get loaded into the `iframe`.

This [blog](http://blog.newitfarmer.com/ajax-framework/ajax-ajax-framework/2289/repost-heres-how-you-get-effectively-a-post-cross-domain-call-including-attached-files-and-multi-part-and-all/) should help and also the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe).