# How do I dynamically update an iframe using Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am developing a page in with a text box, a submit button, and an iframe.

The URL should be put in the text box.  Upon hitting the button, the result should appear in the iframe.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need JavaScript at all. Set the target attribute of your form to the name of the frame, and it will load there.

See also the duplicate [How do you post to an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/168455/1048572).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution for now using js

```
 <form target="#" name="iframeform" action="post">

     <input type="text" value="http://" name="framefood" id="framefood" /><br />
     <button id="feedframe" onclick="completeFrame(); return false;">Send</button><br /><br />
     <iframe id="feedme" width="600" height="400"></iframe>
 </form>
 <script>

     var completeFrame = function(e){
         var feidlId = document.getElementById("framefood");
         var frameSrc    =   feidlId.value;
         var frameId = document.getElementById("feedme");
         frameId.src =   frameSrc;
     }

 </script>
```

Comment: ,, in the text box i typed google.com but it dosent come in the iframe, y is dat so?

Comment: you might need to check that the url being entered has the http:// etc as it will not work properly?

Comment: i did enter the url along with the "http://",but it gives me an error saying "this webpage is not found"

Comment: then its seems the site its looking for is an issue, if it displayed this message within the iframe?