# Why is PHP not seeing the file upload through POST and jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, file, upload

I have this HTML:

```
<form action='uploadhandle.php' method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type='file' class='fileinput' id='photo1' name='photo1'>
<input type='button' id='upload1' name='upload1' value='Upload'>
</form>
```

My jquery code is:

```
$('#upload1').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "uploadhandle.php",
        data: 'photo1='+photo1,
        success: function(data){$('#result_div').html(data)}

        });
```

In my uploadhandle.php, when I try to display the $_POST['photo1'], nothing comes up, it's "undefined".
Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Thanks a lot, 
Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot upload a file via AJAX.  It isn't possible.

What IS possible is using a plugin or another method that "simulates" ajax by creating an iframe and submitting the info in the background.  There are several plugins that handle this, some are very complex, some simply extend the ajax function itself.

That being said, your syntax server side is also wrong.  You have to deal with `$_FILES` not `$_POST` to find and use the submitted file.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestions. I will look into that iframe method. Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload file data through XHR (i.e. ajax). There is a file upload API in [XHR2](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/), but the most practical and cross browser compatible way today seems to use a hidden iframe to do the file upload.

**Edit:** See [How do you post to an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe/168488#168488)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I am looking into your link. Regards