# passing login credentials via iframe

Tags: authentication, post, iframe

I have two different domains/sites, one http and one https. The http site requires login and then users are shown a non-secure page with an iframe that shows content from the https site.

I would like to seamlessly pass login credentials from the http site to the iframe'd https site. I do not want to use jquery. Is it possible to have the iframe use a POST request instead of GET? I would like to encrypt the login info from the http site and POST the encrypted bundle to the https site.

I'm working with php and apache, if it makes a difference.

I found [this article on iframe/POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe) but wasn't sure how to get the form auto-submitted when the http page loads. Maybe that's a line of javascript? Also, while the login page on the http site has a login form, the post-login page that has the iframe on it does not (currently) have a form. Maybe I could make an invisible form to create this POST request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript like this:

```
document.getElementById('someId').submit();
```