# load iframe with very long url parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, iframe, get

I have javascript creating and loading an iframe. The problem is that the url - which contains a dynamic list of parameters used to structure the iframe's content - is way too long to be included in the iframe src (with the GET method).
Is there anyway to load the contents of the iframe with POST or some other method which can handle the large parameter list?

I have tried using javascript to auto-submit a form targeted to the iframe src with the parameter list preloaded - however this method seems to refresh the page (which I would rather not have).

Comment: I would use the form submitting to the iframe method, which shouldn't refresh the page if the iframe has a name and the form's target attribute contains the name of the iframe.

Comment: thanks, I rewrote it again and changed it a little, and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could save this information as a temportary row in a table and simply refer to the id through a single $_GET.

If that seems too complex, simply have a `<form target="iframe_id"` and have jQuery `$.submit()` that form. See [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe?answertab=votes#tab-top) regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do a JQuery modification, then call doPostBack() specifically for that iFrame?

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the whole URL into a variable. Then just put the variable where you are setting a request. I guess it should work.