# Detect Click On Iframe Then Do An Action

Tags: iframe, click, action, detect

I want to add a iframe to my website that has a button in it and when someone clicks on it, it does an action like maybe forward to another page or echo a message. I don't care about the code whether its java, php, html, etc as long as it works. I'm good at coding certain things but this is not one of them, help me out please.

UPDATE:
the iframe is:
    iframe src="http://ipget.tk" /iframe

when its clicked on I want it to go to google.com
the iframe will be on a test page on scazioco.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Jquery you can bind an event to your IFrame :

```
    $('#iframe_id').bind('click', function(event) { 
        window.location = http://www.google.com    
     });
```

Replace #iframe_id with the actual Iframe's ID

Comment: can you give me a full example code that lets say when it detects a click on an iframe it forwards to google. please.

Comment: Thank you! One last question, if I wanted to change the website google.com to a php action that brings random rows from mysql can I do that? So like it gives random links from a database?

Comment: oh and what if there is 2 iframs and I wanted them both clicked before forwards to the next page?

Comment: Are you saying you want to POST to an Iframe? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment about 2 iFrames being clicked at once?

Comment: Nevermind everything I said, I just want to know if there was two iframes and I wanted them both clicked on and then an action to go to the next page, what would be the code? They both must be clicked on first then go to the new page.

Comment: Just use the code above twice, with 2 different iFrame Ids and both going to whatever location you want them to redirect.

Comment: Can you please mark this as answered? I see you have just started using StackOverflow, just a suggestion :)