# IE9 download issue php pdf and other files

Tags: php, internet-explorer, http-headers, download

I have a PHP function which downloads differents files after clicking on a button (If we click on PDF button, it will load a pdf file, if we click on DOC button, it will load a doc file). It is the same function for both buttons.

My problem is when I download a file. If it's the PDF, IE will open an other page, and will close it and give me the choice to download the file, but if it's the DOC, IE will open an other page, and not close it.

The code is (for me) the same, I don't see any differences.

```
<pre>
<code>
    public function lettrecadrageAction() {

     $nom = $_POST['type'];
     switch ($nom):

      case 'Fichier DOC' :

       $path = "ddl/lettre_de_cadrage.doc";
       header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
       header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
       header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=lettre_de_cadrage.doc");
       header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
       header('Expires: 0');
       header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
       header('Pragma: public');
       header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
       ob_clean();
       flush();
       readfile($path);
       break;

      case 'Fichier PDF' :

       $path = "ddl/lettre_de_cadrage.pdf";
       header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
       header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
       header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=lettre_de_cadrage.pdf");
       header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
       header('Expires: 0');
       header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
       header('Pragma: public');
       header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
       ob_clean();
       flush();
       readfile($path);
       break;
      endswitch;
     exit;
    }
</code>
</pre>
```

The Js action for click

```
<pre>
    <code>
$('.ldc_dl').click(function() {
        var f = document.createElement("form");
        f.method = "POST";
        f.name = "form";
        f.target = "_blank";
        f.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
        f.action = "http://" + document.domain + "/Exploitation/lettrecadrage/";
        var fHtml = document.createElement("input");
        fHtml.type = "text";
        fHtml.name = "type";
        fHtml.value = $(this).html();
        console.log(fHtml);
        var fSubmit = document.createElement("input");
        fSubmit.type = "submit";
        f.appendChild(fHtml);
        f.appendChild(fSubmit);
        document.body.appendChild(f);
        f.submit();
        document.body.removeChild(f);

        return true;
    }) </code>
</pre>
```

The HTML code for the buttons

```
<pre>
  <code>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="ldc"> 
        <p>La lettre de cadrage est disponible en <button id="ldc_dl_doc" class="btn btn-link ldc_dl" type="button">Fichier DOC</button></p>
        <p> Ou en <button id="ldc_dl_pdf" class="btn btn-link ldc_dl" type="button">Fichier PDF</button></p>
    </div>
  </code>
</pre>
```

(The buttons are 'Fichier PDF' and 'Fichier DOC')

**Edit - Solution**

With the help of jbl in comments, I resolved my problem, using an iframe :

```
var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
frame.setAttribute("src", "_blank");
```

and modify my form target

```
            f.target = frame;
```

Comment: You should also show the html (and js) code which triggers the download

Comment: So I did, thanks for tip!

Comment: good ! I guess your problem comes from f.target = "_blank"; I would suggest posting to a tiny iframe on your page instead. See for example : http://stackoverflow.com/q/168455/1236044

Comment: And what do I use as src for the iframe?

Comment: I guess anything returning an empty html doc would be good enough (just to avoid 404)

Comment: I admit I didn't know iframe, so how do I create one? I have
        var frame = document.createElement("iframe"); for now, which attributes Do i give to it?

Comment: It works with 
        var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
        frame.setAttribute("src", "_blank");
.... 
       f.target = frame;

Comment: Great ! Instead of editing, you should post your solution as an answer to your own question, and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of jbl in comments, I resolved my problem, using an iframe :

```
var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
frame.setAttribute("src", "_blank");
```

and modify my form target

```
        f.target = frame;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Content-Transfer-Encoding` header is used in MIME email messages. It has no any sense to send it over HTTP.

`Content-Disposition: attachment;` header says the browser to save it rather then open in the browser. So instead of `Content-Type: application/force-download` i would suggest to use proper content-type for PDF and DOC files:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word
```

Comment: I replace by what you have suggested, but it still opens an empty page which doesnt close by itself.