# Make Sinatra redirect to top level not to iframe

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, sinatra

I'm using oauth2 with an iframe. In my redirect_uri method in app.rb I am doing a redirect to '/'. But, this is causing my '/' page to show up in the iframe, not at the top level. Can I fix this in my ruby code? Or, do I need to make a change to my HTML or Javascript?

In my HTML I have:

```
<form action="https://XXX.XXXX.com/XXX/authorize" method="get" id="XXXForm" target="XXX">
    <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="my_id"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri" value="https://somesite.com/redirect/XXX/"/>
</form>
```

And, at the end of the HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#XXX').show();
 $('#XXXForm').submit();
</script>
```

And, in my app.rb, I have:

```
get '/redirect/XXX/' do
  redirect_to_url = '/login'
  if params[:code] then # authorized okay
    # other processing, e.g., get token
    redirect_to_url = '/'
  end
  p "redirect #{redirect_to_url}"
  redirect to redirect_to_url
end
```

Comment: My E.S.P. isn't working well enough to read your code, maybe I need a coffee… I think you're going to have to share some of it ;)

Comment: Okay, I just shared some code:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/168488/335847 and see if that helps.

If you're going to use javascript, then I'd:

- make it an ajax call instead
- don't bother with the redirect within Sinatra
- just return the status of the request ([one of the 2xx's for success or the 4xx or 5xx's for failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes))
- remember to use [`halt`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Halting) so as not to return a body (unless you want to, but you could still use `halt`)
- use `request.xhr?` if you need it
- use a success handler (or similar) to redirect the page, probably by using the global `window`.

Comment: Excellent! I actually ended up using a success handler calling a js function in window.parent. Thanks.