# How to stop redirecting to the php page when submitting an HTML form

Tags: php, html, email, forms

I've got your run of the mill form, with a PHP script to validate and email it off.

```
<form id="contactForm" action="contact.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <p>
            <label>NAME:</label>
            <input name="name"  id="name" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>EMAIL:</label>
            <input name="email"  id="email" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>COMMENTS:</label>
            <textarea  name="comments"  id="comments" rows="5" cols="20" ></textarea>
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value=" " name="submit" id="submit" /></p>
    </fieldset>
    <p id="error" class="warning">Message</p>
</form>
```

The problem is, that when I click `submit`, it takes me off the page I was on (filling out the form) and takes me to a blank white page - `contact.php`.

Is there any way I can stay on the original `contact.html` page after clicking `submit` and just let the emailing happen in the background?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

Comment: `action="contact.html"` well you could use ajax, but you actully need to

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is your best best.  If not, the quick and dirty way would be to put a php block at the top of you page and put all the stuff from your contact.php in an if(isset($_post['data'])) statement.

Brief example

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['variable_from_form']))
{
    // send mail, insert in database, etc. stuffs 

}
?>
```

Basically, if there is post data, do something, if not, just write the page as normal

Comment: i would say 'tried and true' not 'quick and dirty' to the 'all in one' approach

Comment: It always reminds me of writing asp pages pre .Net [and still with webforms] with tons of code at the top.  Now I usually just json the data -> $.post() to the server -> Do the stuff -> Insert a little "thanks for contacting us bleh bleh bleh ... Link to Index" on the page.  I think it just makes me *feel* like I've learned something since asp

Answer (score 0):

Php is doing the job assigned: it is redirecting to the page you asked for in the action="" tag.
If you need to validate an email or login,  you should use the same contact.php form to do both: enter user email and validate and/or login or whatever you want to do.

At the begining of the contact.php use php script  to receive submitted fields,  validate, sanitize and insert or whatever.

```
<?php

 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
 {  
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $email=filter_var($id_post, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);  
    if(empty($email) )
      {$error=['email']="enter a valid email"}
    else {
       $user_email=$email;
       }
  } 
   if(empty($errors) && $_POST)  
      {
         //with $user_email defined and sanitized you can do whatever you want:         insert,    edit, query, email.
     }
  elseif ($errors || !$_POST) 
    {
    ?>
```

Here, put all the html form,  at the end, close the open php.

```
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put an iframe on your page that initially loads a blank page within it and have the form's target be the iframe so it will post into the iframe.

Have the iframe large enough so that you can put a simple message like "Your information has been accepted" can be printed by contact.php

Here's a link that tells you how to do it.

[How do you post to an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe)

Answer (score -1):

you might use **javascript** (**Ajax**) to communicate with your server, that way it will continue using the same html file.

Another way it is to rename your html file to **.php** extension and work on this file.

Good luck!