# How to show a php page in the html page that called it?

Tags: php, html

I'm new to php and html, so I'm not sure that the title is easy to understand, sorry for that. The problem is simple , I have an html form like this:

```
<form action="action_calibration.php" method=post>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="fast" checked>Fast Calibration
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="old">Old Calibration
  <br><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="ScanVPlus" value="yes" checked>Scan 
  <br><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Bitwise" value="yes">Bitwise Offset 
  <br><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="All_channel" value="yes">Calibration 
  <br><br>
  Output Folder:<input type="textfield" name="output" value="Results/">
  <br><br>
  Hw Description File:<input type="textfield" name="Hw Description File " value="settings/Calibration2CBC.xml">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

The action_calibration.php is a php page that execute a binary file and show the results on the php page, what I'm tring to do is print these results on the page containing the form, without open another one. I hope that you can understand what I mean. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you need to search around a bit for ajax and php, and read some tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including an iframe sibling the form, with a name, and giving the form a target attribute.

Related: [How do you post to an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe)

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I was looking for