# php & html - how to use iframe for a redirected page

Tags: php, html

I have a html form with post method something like this :

```html
<form action="xml.php" method="post">
    <textarea rows="15" cols="30" name="user"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Export to xml">
</form>
```

When user presses the `submit` button page redirects to `xml.php`
and `xml.php`'s contents changes by user input. (POSTing method)

I want to use an `iframe` tag for `xml.php` But I don't know how ?
because it redirects to the `xml.php` how can we `iframe` result of `xml.php` in current page ? (showing the result of `xml.php` in current page)

Answer (score 1):

You can make an ajax post to xml.php and then print the the returned result.

eg: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

If you want to use iframe then

```
<form action="xml.php" method="post" target="my_iframe">
    <textarea rows="15" cols="30" name="user"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Export to xml">
</form>

<iframe name="my_iframe" src="xml.php"></iframe>
```

Pay attention that the content of iframe is loaded when the page load so maybe you want to hide the iframe and then show after the post.

Similar question:
[How do you post to an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe)