# Form - submit POST request to multiple iframes

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe, form-submit

I know that it is possible to [submit POST request to an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe) by using `target` attribute.

Is there any way to submit POST request from one form to multiple iframes at the same time?

Both HTML and JS solutions are acceptable.

Comment: Just curious but why would you want to do that?

Comment: @NickZ good question! I have markup with two iframes, one is shown for devices with large viewports > 1000px and other is shown for mobile devices. Both iframes should have the same source but different styling and positioning.

Comment: So would you rather want to submit the form to one of these iframes? Whichever one is in use? Or am I misunderstanding something

Comment: @NickZ I'm using the [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and my project is responsive. By resizing browser you can see one or another version, so both iframes should contain actual response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Javascript solution would be your best bet.

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="xyz" value="random data" />
  <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

In JS, you would attach an event listener to your form when it is submitted. The listener would trigger a function that could send the form data to multiple targets:

```
var form = document.getElementById("form");

if(form.attachEvent) {
  form.attachEvent("submit", submitForm);

} else {
  form.addEventListener("submit", submitForm);
}

function submitForm(e) {
  if(e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  this.target = "first_iframe";
  this.submit();

  var secondForm = this.cloneNode();
  secondForm.target = "second_iframe";
  secondForm.submit();
}
```

Comment: sorry for delay in my answer, but this solution isn't working, [proof](https://jsfiddle.net/mjshzbdo/1/)

Comment: Not a problem. I have edited the submitForm function and tested it on the link that you sent. It now works.