# How to mask the url in htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need some help. How do I hide the URL in the address bar to mask them using .htaccess when a user click on the submit button?

Example: When a user put their email address and click on the submit button, it will redirect them to the site:

```
www.3rdpartysite.com
```

How I can make it to show as my domain name as `www.myowndomain.com` instead of `www.3rdpartysite.com`?

Can you please show me an example code for the htaccess?

Comment: I don't believe you can do that with in the way you are thinking.  What about using an `<iframe>`?

Comment: That would be a good idea, how I can use iframe using this `<input type="hidden" name="thankyou_url" value="https://www.3rdpartysite.com"/>`??

Comment: can I be able to call the iframe from my main page when I use the index.html in my subfolder so I could call the iframe from the main page to redirect me to the site `www.3rdpartysite.com`??

Comment: redirect you to which index.html?  You can submit your form to an iframe by using the target attribute of the form tag, or you could have the form itself inside of an iframe.

Comment: the index.html from the main page like where you visit the site. How I can call the iframe using the iframe by using the target attribute of the form tag? can you show me an example please?

Comment: I want to put the iframe code on the bottom of the html code so I could use to call them from the form. How i could do that?

Comment: Example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/168488/747678

Comment: You can do this using proxy and the [P flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) So you can use this to pass the parameters to the 3rd party site without changing your  URL.

Comment: @PanamaJack thank you very much for this, how i can use my ref instead of using this `RewriteRule "/(.*)\.(jpg|gif|png)$" "http://images.example.com/$1.$2" [P]`??

Comment: what type of link would the user click on that would be sent to the other site and what's the other site's URL format?

Comment: @PanamaJack the link would be `empowernetwork.com/totalshortcut/?id=1234`