# Send data without leaving the original page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The watchlistinsert.php sends some information to my database and i want it to send without leaving the original page where i clicked from. I think i need to use some ajax, I have tried a few different things, but it is not working. Hope someone can help me out.

```
 echo "<td>"."<a id='add' href=\"watchlistinsert.php?symbol=$symbol&price=$price&watchlistgroupid=$watchlistgroupid\">Add</a>"  ."</td>";
```

Comment: Show us what you tried and where it failed

Comment: yes, you need to use ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You have some options at your disposal:

1. You can - as you have already written - do it via Ajax
2. You might be able to use WebSockets
3. You could send an HTTP-Request to a hidden IFrame: [How do you post to an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe)
4. You could use JavaScript to simply load an Image from your server ... and the URL said image would be the URL to your php script

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with jQuery by using the `ajax()` function: 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/path/to/my/file.php",
  data: {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2'
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // do something
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // do something
  }
})
```

Read about all the parameters you can use at the above link.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td>"."<a id='add' onclick=\"$.ajax({url:'watchlistinsert.php',data:{ symbol:'$symbol', price:'$price', watchlistgroupid:'$watchlistgroupid'}, success:function(response){alert('inserted!');}});\" href=\"javascript:\">Add</a>"  ."</td>";
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanatory text, not just for the OP but also other people who come to your answer in the future with the same (or very similar) problem.