# How to post variables from iframe to child iframe

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I am new in Javascript and trying how to get variables from iframe to child iframe (locally). The 1st iframe (iframesrc.php) can show variables from the parent (index.php) but the 2nd iframe (iframesrc2.php) cannot. I need the 2nd iframe to show variables from the 1st without losing all variables when clicking the button "insert ticket". Please help.. Thanks in advance. And sorry for my english..

Here are my codes (index.php, iframesrc.php, iframesrc2.php) :

**index.php**

index.php contains ajax script (in header) to post variables to iframe. It works and successfully show a variable on target page (iframesrc.php)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Post to an iFrame using Ajax</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>

            function ajax(m,u,p,c){
                /*
                    m=method
                    u=url
                    p=params {name:value}
                    c=callback
                */
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 )c.call(this,xhr.response);
                };

                var params=[];
                for( var n in p )params.push(n+'='+p[n]);

                switch( m.toLowerCase() ){
                    case 'post': p=params.join('&'); break;
                    case 'get': u+='?'+params.join('&'); p=null; break; 
                }

                xhr.open( m.toUpperCase(), u, true );
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.send( p );
            }


            function initialise(){
                var bttn=document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]')[0];
                    bttn.onclick=function(event){
                        var params={};
                        var fd=new FormData( document.forms['myform'] );
                        for( var key of fd.keys() ) params[key]=fd.get(key);
                        ajax.call( this, 'post', document.querySelectorAll('iframe[name="ifr"]')[0].src, params, cbfd );
                    };
            }

            function cbfd(r){
                var iframe=document.querySelectorAll('iframe[name="ifr"]')[0].contentWindow.document;
                iframe.body.innerHTML=r;
            }


            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',initialise,false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="myform" method="post">
            <input name="tid" value="<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['tid'])) { echo htmlentities($_REQUEST['tid']); }?>" type="text" placeholder="VAL1" />
            <input type="button" value="Generate" />
        </form>
        <iframe name="ifr" src="iframesrc.php"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

**iframesrc.php**

iframesrc.php contains script that store variables (**value 1**) by echoing :

```
<?php
echo $_POST['tid'];
?>
```

And it works. Also contain an ajax script at header to show **value 2** at the next target page / iframesrc2.php (not work). Please help me :(

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>iframesrc.php</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>

            function ajax(m,u,p,c){
                /*
                    m=method
                    u=url
                    p=params {name:value}
                    c=callback
                */
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 )c.call(this,xhr.response);
                };

                var params=[];
                for( var n in p )params.push(n+'='+p[n]);

                switch( m.toLowerCase() ){
                    case 'post': p=params.join('&'); break;
                    case 'get': u+='?'+params.join('&'); p=null; break; 
                }

                xhr.open( m.toUpperCase(), u, true );
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.send( p );
            }


            function initialise(){
                var bttn=document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]')[0];
                    bttn.onclick=function(event){
                        var params={};
                        var fd=new FormData( document.forms['myform'] );
                        for( var key of fd.keys() ) params[key]=fd.get(key);
                        ajax.call( this, 'post', document.querySelectorAll('iframe[name="ifr"]')[0].src, params, cbfd );
                    };
            }

            function cbfd(r){
                var iframe=document.querySelectorAll('iframe[name="ifr"]')[0].contentWindow.document;
                iframe.body.innerHTML=r;
            }


            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',initialise,false);
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
<?php
echo $_POST['tid'];
?>
<form name="myform" method="post">
    <input name="notikjarkom" value="<?php if (isset($notikjarkom)) { echo htmlentities($notikjarkom); }?>" type="text" placeholder="VAL2" />
    <input type="button" value="Insert Ticket" />
</form>
    <iframe name="ifr" src="iframesrc2.php"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**iframesrc2.php**

iframesrc2.php is the second iframe (the child iframe that I want it to show the variable requested from iframesrc.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>iframesrc2.php</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
echo $_POST['notikjarkom'];
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the screenshot :
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYKWW.jpg)

When I filled a value (value 1) and clicked Generate, the value 1 is successfully shown in iframesrc.php, but when I then filled a value (value 2) and clicked Insert Ticket, the value 2 not shown in the second iframe (iframesrc2.php) Please help me...

Comment: are they on the same domain + subdomain? and you can always use `GET`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe

Comment: @Cemal Yes, they are on localhost. The first iframe can show the value but not the second one. I just added some explanation and a screenshot, thank you

Comment: @KarloKokkak Thank you for the response, but I do not think it is a duplicate with the linked, I read it and they talk about how to post to an iframe, in my case I can successfully post from parent to an iframe but failed to post from iframe to child iframe, as I just added some explanations and a screenshot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It solved by changing the second iframe of not using the Javascript.
I just replaced the form and iframe sections with the following :

```
<form action="iframesrc2.php" target="ifr2" method="post">
    <input name="notikjarkom" value="<?php if (isset($notikjarkom)) { echo htmlentities($notikjarkom); }?>" type="text" placeholder="PASTE NOTIK JARKOM DISINI DAN TEKAN INSERT TICKET" />
    <input type="submit" value="Insert Ticket" />
</form>
    <iframe name="ifr2"></iframe>
```

Thank you and yes I need to learn more about everything :)