# how to change the behaviour of httpservlet to use doPost in adf?

Tags: jsf-2, oracle-adf

i have button that it's action is to set inlineframe Src attribute in the backing bean , and this the code for the button :

```
 <af:button 
  <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{Bean.iframeURL}" value="http://myurl.com/data&user=user&pass=1234"/>
 </af:button>
```

when i press that button a http get request is sent (as in picture) to the url and the respone is rendered on the webpage

```
 <af:inlineFrame styleClass="IFrame" binding="#{Bean.reportFrameUI}" source="#{Bean.iframeURL}"
                        id="if1"/>
```

,

[image]
i want to override that and force to use doPost  as it's done nomraly in HTML forms for eg :

```
<form action="http://<HOSTNAME>:<PORT>/analytics/saw.dll?" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="Cmd" value="Answers">
<input type="hidden" name="nqUser" value="<ADMIN_USER>">
<input type="hidden" name="nqPassword" value="<PASSWORD>">
<input type="submit" value="Answers">
</form>
```

Comment: You should ediut your question and add a [mcve] as it appears to be rather unclear so far. This is possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe#168488

Comment: This does not make it any clearer (it is not a [mcve]  by a long shot...