# How to avoid query string while loading an iframe

Tags: asp.net, angular, query-string

I need to load this [www.somedomain.com/Sample/Sample.aspx?ID1=12&ID2=13](http://www.somedomain.com/Sample/Sample.aspx?ID1=12&ID2=13) in an Angular web app

But here, instead of passing these value in query string, I need to pass it in hidden way. Guide me with some solution.

Looking for something like a post method to pass these parameters in headers.

Comment: We do not have full picture of the whole process. I think you can send post parameters this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe Maybe if the same website is activated before you can use server session. You can also use hashed value to hide the ids and still send it within query.

Comment: What do you mean by "hiding"? All the logic happens in your clients browser, so there should be no need to "hide" anything. Passing parameters in the request body is also not a good idea to "hide" anything. It still can be seen by your client's browser.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.