# Local POST data send, how?

Tags: javascript, php, post

I have a block printer that can be printed by sending POST data.
My problem is that I have PHP running on the server, so I can't call 127.0.0.1 from there.
It is not possible with JavaScript because of the CROS rule.

What is the solution?
I'm interested in all solutions!

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your question - I have read it several times and still don't understand the issue

Comment: If the printer is connected to another computer, you'll need the IP address of this machine, and it must be within the same network like the webserver to directly call it.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, yes:
I have a printer that is connected to the local network and is waiting for POST methods at the following IP address: http://127.0.0.1:30000/
I have a website that is hosted on example.com and I use PHP
If I were to call 127.0.0.1 on a server, of course it would not be good. But if I call it in ajax, it is not possible because of the CROS rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to post data using iframe like this

```
<form target="myIframe" action="http://localhost/post.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="someval" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<iFrame src="" name="myIframe"></iFrame>
```

more examples at original post
[How do you post to an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe)

Comment: What exactly is that suppose to solve? And why?

Comment: TS wanted to print server-generated data on local printer, which available at http://127.0.0.1:30000/, but POST via JS is prohibited by CORS

Comment: Then shouldn't the action be: `http://127.0.0.1:30000`? And where did `post.php` come from?

Comment: That's right, it should. But at the moment I wrote it I had no details about that.